# .sh links stopped being executed by double click in Kubuntu

Tags: bash, scripts, kubuntu, symbolic-link

I am starting to experience a weird thing on Kubuntu. Double clicking on .sh **links** stopped working (expecting it to run), but double clicking on actual .sh file works.

System information:

[image: SYstem information]

Double clicking on sh link example:

[image: Example what does not work]

You might notice fast icon appear and disappear next to cursor.

Anyone experienced this? Does anyone know how to fix this and what might be the cause? Again, double clicking on actual .sh files works - programs are executed, just links do not work.

Comment: could you open a terminal in pycharm.sh's folder and execute it? add the output to the question please

Comment: Executing ANY .sh from terminal (sh <sh file path>) is also OK. Specifically running pycharm.sh gives a few warnings about missing plugins, but it is not related. The program opens fine.